# Connecting HDD to PC having copied files to HDD from phone triggers error check

Tags: external-sd, file-management

I have a brand new, formatted with exFAT 1TB external hard drive which I'm connecting to my phone via a USB hub. I can copy files to it no problem.

However when I connect to my Windows 7 PC it says that there is an error and tries running the Error Checking tool. It doesn't find any issue however.

My question is why does it think this and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Does this happen every time? Do you properly eject/unmount drive from phone storage before disconnecting cable? See Windows Event Viewer for detailed `chkdsk` log to see what kind of errors it suspects/finds on filesystem.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I ejected it from my phone and plugged it into my PC and it was fine. I was just plugging it out even when the transfer was completed so didn't think this would be an issue. I notice there isn't an option in Windows 7 to eject this HDD. Please put this as an answer and I will mark as the solution.

Comment: Then I assume the main problem is not the phone but your Windows 7 system that does not allow to eject the drive (are you sure you just have missed the icon?). This triggers the "ejected without correct unmount" flag on the HDD which is just ignored by the phone and later your Windows system complains about it.

Comment: @CiaranMartin there is always an option to "un-mount" or "safely remove" or "eject" storage devices, on all OSes, for all filesystems. @Robert if Android un-mounts the filesystem properly, that "unclean" flag should be removed irrespective of who set that. And Windows won't complain anymore. Android always runs `fsck` on removable storage before mounting.